# Java error: not a statement if-else

Tags: java

```
private byte isTargetEast(IRobot robot) {

byte resultE = 0;   
if (robot.getLocation().x > robot.getTargetLocation().x) {
    resultE = -1;
} else if (robot.getLocation().x < robot.getTargetLocation().x) {
    resultE = 1; 
} else  {
    resultE = 0; }
return resultE;

// returning 1 for 'yes', -1 for 'no' and 0 for 'same latitude'.



}
```

gives errors 'erro: illegal start of expression' and 'error ';' expected, 6 errors total, 2 illegal starts, 4semicolons, all on the private byte line

Comment: It looks like you want to do assignments, instead you have a boolean condition. Remove the && and the parentheses, separate each assignment with a semicolon.

Comment: You are not doing anything with the boolean value of the if/else body, thats the problem

Comment: @SteBra what loop are you talking about?

Comment: your code alignment is terrible (a mean comment perhaps now, it will help you if you stay away from writing your code that way)

Comment: We know you have clearly invalid syntax but you haven't told us what you want to do so we can't rightly tell you how to fix it. Note that while some languages do allow a statement like `(a = b) && (c = d);`, I have no idea why you would want to use it here based on what it usually means.

Comment: Don't use the parenthesis around Vir = IRobot.BEHIND;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of the if-condition is totally wrong. What you want to do? You are mixing assign and condition code.

You can do assign like this:

```java
if (chanceDir >= 0.5) {
   Dir = IRobot.AHEAD;
   Vir = IRobot.BEHIND;
   Hir = IRobot.AHEAD;
   Sir = IRobot.BEHIND;
} else { 
   Dir = IRobot.RIGHT;
   Vir = IRobot.LEFT;
   Hir = IRobot.LEFT;
   Sir = IRobot.RIGHT; 
}

if (oppchanceDir >= 0.5) {
   Dir = IRobot.BEHIND;
   Vir = IRobot.AHEAD;
   Hir = IRobot.BEHIND;
   Sir = IRobot.AHEAD; 
}else { 
   Dir = IRobot.LEFT; 
   Vir = IRobot.RIGHT;
   Hir = IRobot.RIGHT;
   Sir = IRobot.LEFT; 
}
```

Or you can do check conditions like that:

```java
if (chanceDir >= 0.5 && ((Dir == IRobot.AHEAD) && (Vir == IRobot.BEHIND) && (Hir == IRobot.AHEAD) && (Sir == IRobot.BEHIND))) {
  // do something here

}else if((Dir == IRobot.RIGHT) && (Vir == IRobot.LEFT) && (Hir == IRobot.LEFT) && (Sir == IRobot.RIGHT)){
  // do something here
}else{
  // do something here
}

if (oppchanceDir >= 0.5 && ((Dir == IRobot.BEHIND) && (Vir == IRobot.AHEAD) && (Hir == IRobot.BEHIND) && (Sir == IRobot.AHEAD))) {
  // do something here

} else if ((Dir == IRobot.LEFT) && (Vir == IRobot.RIGHT) && (Hir == IRobot.RIGHT) && (Sir == IRobot.LEFT)) {  
  // do something here
}else{
  // do something here
}
```

Comment: I am trying to change the value for a group of variables under a single condition. and yeah the boolean usage was stupid :D thanks

Comment: EDIT: I tried the first assignment you suggested, but it still comes out with the 'error: not a statement'

Comment: Can you show your enum. On which line the erros apears?

Comment: its every line within the if/else statements

Comment: You'll need to show us what you tried. Mosa's code should work.

Comment: See my comment to the question itself. You added parentheses to Mosa's code, which is breaking the code. Take them out and try it again.

Comment: AND THANK YOU @ kathyA and Mosa, parenthesis errors , you were right

Comment: any chance i can ask you about another part, im getting some errors on a bit of code that i had to input... its not my own design